# Pandas - Plot two dataframes, one as marker

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have two dataFrames. Both have datetime as index.

```
                     PM 2.5  PM 10  entry_id
created_at
2018-06-13 16:11:43    4.67   5.17        20
2018-06-13 16:12:43    5.04   5.59        21
2018-06-13 16:13:43    5.40   6.10        22
2018-06-13 16:14:43    5.03   5.55        23
2018-06-13 16:15:43    4.93   5.44        24

                          action              end_at
done_at
2018-11-10 10:15:00  Babymassage 2018-11-10 12:00:00
2018-11-24 10:15:00  Babymassage 2018-11-24 12:00:00
2018-12-01 10:15:00  Babymassage 2018-12-01 12:00:00
2018-12-01 14:30:00  staubsaugen                 NaT
2018-12-01 15:30:00  Ausser Haus 2018-12-03 12:00:00
```

I want to plot the time on x and the PM 2.5 and PM 10 on y. And the action column from the second dataframe should be a text label with x from index.
Is that possible with pandas? I try this but doesent work

```
#Import Modules
from sql_connection import sql_connector
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

#Get data from SQL server
df = pd.read_sql("feinstaub_wohnzimmer",con=sql_connector("mysql","localhost","3306","root","xxx","feinstaub"),index_col="created_at")
df1 = pd.read_sql("wohnzimmer_aktionen",con=sql_connector("mysql","localhost","3306","root","xxx","feinstaub"),index_col="done_at")

#Sort index
df = df.sort_index(axis=0)
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=0)

#Group by Day 
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))))
dfd = dict(tuple(df1.groupby(df1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))))

#Plot for Today
today = str(date.today())
ax = dfd[today].plot(marker="o", label="action")
dfs[today].plot( y=["PM 2.5","PM 10"], kind='line', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

It should be look like this 
[image]
or do you think it is possible to plot also a sign for the duration of the action when i use the additional iformation at the end_at column?

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the data frames in tuples nested in dictionaries?

Comment: Just spent the last hour trying to plot this, I have pretty much no idea what you're trying to do. I kept wanting to quit, but felt like what you were asking was so simple that I must have been missing something. The numerical data you provided doesn't even plot like the graph you're looking to get. strftime throws up errors when I try to run it, and even when I take that out there's bugs on bugs on bugs. 10/10 would not try to code this again.